# Is this Orchid dying?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, flowering, orchids

I've had these orchid for about a month and it was doing really well but now it  looks like its dying.What type of orchid is this? How do I make it bloom again?

[image: Dying Orchid]

[image]

Comment: Can we get another picture from a different angle? Specifically, one where the lens angle is perpendicular to the pot?

Comment: @Rob okay i added another picture. Thank you so much for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay yes as I suspected your orchid is fine. In-fact, it's doing quite well considering. Orchids cycle is something like: build up as much energy as possible, expend all of that energy during a long bloom cycle, go dormant and build up more energy for the next bloom cycle. Continue on with your normal care regime. If your delicate about it you can probobly probe around the root base and see if it isn't already growing a new pup without damaging the plant. There may be multiples or maybe none yet but eventually, when the plant is ready, a new pup will appear and start to grow.

Comment: Okay thanks @Rob any other tips for taking care of orchids?

Comment: Well.. it depends on the variety but personally I have never had much trouble with them. They are fairly well domesticated plants which do not require a lot of special maintenance. In-fact, if you are looking for a challenge, you might try one of the following varietys:  Disa, Pecteiluls Radiata, Subrosa, Isas, Aurata, Tripetaloides and Uniflora or (if you are REALLY looking for a challange) Masdevallias and or Draculas.

Comment: This appears to be a Cymbidium. Once the flowers are done, they flower stalk does exactly what your photos show. Looks perfectly fine, as Rob says.